# DOM windows.location to iframe

Tags: html, dom

Is it possible to use DOM windows.location to load web page into an iframe?
Or some other way for instance:

```
...
document.getElementByID("content").innerHTML ="http://google.com";
...

<div id="content"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: In JQuery you could `div.load('http://www.google.com')`

Comment: Your question is terribly unclear. Please elaborate on intended result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is probably the `.src` property of the iframe:

```
document.getElementByID("content").src = "http://google.com";
```

(assuming "content" is the ID of the inner frame)